# Can I delete UnitySetup .exe files from AppData Temp folder?

Tags: unity, windows, filesystem

Can I safely delete the following Unity-related files in order to clear up space?

- %APPDATA%\Local\Temp\unityhub......\UnitySetup64-2022.3.7f1.exe
- %APPDATA%\Local\Temp\unityhub.......\UnitySetup64-2021.3.23f1.exe

[image]

Comment: Related post on Super User asking about [if it's safe to delete AppData\Local\Temp content in general](https://superuser.com/q/571901/567870). Still fine to have the more specific Unity question here though, especially considering that the answer seems to vary.

Answer (score 2):

Anything in the temp folder should always be treated with the understanding that it may disappear at any given time. This means you should not store critical information that your program depends on in that directory.

In addition, this is the installer for the corresponding Unity version which is needed for just the installation. UnityHub can redownload them if you need to install a specific version again.

(Just because no critical needed information should be stored in temp, some programs still do so. But in this case, you are safe to delete those files)